# How to match a sequence of whitespaces with c++11 regex

Tags: regex, c++11

```
std::string str = "ahw    \t\n";
std::regex re(R"((\s)*)");
std::smatch mr;
if (std::regex_search(str, mr, re))
{
    std::cout << "match found: " << mr.size() << "\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mr.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::string strrep = mr.str(i);
        int len = mr.length(i);
        std::cout << "index: " << i << "len : " << len << " string: '" << strrep << "'\n";
    }
}
std::string newStr = std::regex_replace(str, re, "");
std::cout << "new string: '" << newStr << "'\n";
```

result:

[image: vc12_regex_result]

What I expect: `only 1 match`, `strrep` should be `'    \t\n'`, and len should be `len(strrep) = 6`. But both vc12 and gcc4.9.2 show the above result.

What's wrong with my understand? How could I match the whitespace sequence `'      \t\n'`?

Comment: did you want t remove `\t` or `\n`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I do not want to remove whitespaces. I want to get the whitespaces from the `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn `\s*` to `\s+` in your regex because `\s*` matches an empty string also(*ie, `\s*` matches zero or more spaces*) also and you don't need to have a capturing group.

Comment: You should explain why.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: but `*` is greedy match, IMO it should match as much as possible of whitespaces.

Comment: not only `*`, `+` is also a greedy one. The main matter is `*` matches the preceding token **0** or more times but `+` would repeat the previous token that is `\s` one or more times.

Comment: The reason for this is that the `(\s)*` matches `ahw` at the start as well! The match is found at the start of the string, where no whitespace exists; the match has zero length, but it is valid. As pointed out by @AvinashRaj, if you change the `*` to `+` it will stop matching at the start of the string and will only match when it finds at least one whitespace.